# How can i get a Value with Alter Table without the ``?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a problem with my code. I want to build a GUI where the user can add a new column in the MySQL database.

```py
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE Benutzer ADD %s INT NOT NULL",(NeueSpalte,))
```

When I write this I get the error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Ultimaker' INT NOT NULL' at line 1

But when i write:

```py
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE Benutzer ADD `%s` INT NOT NULL",(NeueSpalte,))
```

it works. But then I get a new column with `Value`.
I want to ask if there is a possibility to get the Value without the ``?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use only string comcatination

```
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE Benutzer ADD {} INT NOT NULL".format(NeueSpalte))
```

Replacement in prepared statemenst are only allowed for values

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can use next code:

```
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE Benutzer ADD " + NeueSpalte + " INT NOT NULL")
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i wanted !

Comment: Please check @nbk solution, it may be better